# Most efficient way to retrieve recent uploads from multiple channels with YouTube API v3

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

Using a list of channel IDs such as:

channel_ids = ['UC6nSFpj9HTCZ5t-N3Ra3-HB', 'UC6nSFpjSEBUCZ5t-N3Ra3-HB', 'UC6nrst90rsd3Z5t-N3Ra3-HC', 'UC6nSFpjd329th0rt-tuTH3-HA']

I want to retrieve the 50 most recent video uploads for all those channels using the YouTube Data API v3, using as few http requests and as little time as possible.

The way I'm currently doing it is:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=key)

channel_ids = ['UC6nSFpj9HTCZ5t-N3Ra3-HB', 'UC6nSFpjSEBUCZ5t-N3Ra3-HB', 'UC6nrst90rsd3Z5t-N3Ra3-HC', 'UC6nSFpjd329th0rt-tuTH3-HA']
videos_by_channel = {}

for channel_id in channel_ids:

    search_response = youtube.search().list(part="id",
                                            type='video',
                                            order='date',
                                            channelId=channel_id,
                                            maxResults=50).execute()

    videoIds = []
    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            videoIds.append(search_result['id']['videoId'])

    search_response = youtube.videos().list(
                                            id=",".join(videoIds),
                                            part="id,snippet"
                                            ).execute()

    videos_by_channel[channel_id] = search_response
```

It works but uses a lot of server calls and it isn't exactly fast. I've read the documentation but can't find a faster method, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send multiple request with [Sending Batch Requests](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch)

Comment: Does it work for requests of the YouTube api version 3 ? Since your link is part of the Cloud Storage api.

Comment: Yes, it does. You can use apiclient.http.BatchHttpRequest to create batch request easily.